# What would be the best approach to solve below mentioned problem, using current state of Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

We have two datasets,

one set S1 contains some information about products, has 2 columns (as follows: `ProductName, C2`) with 500K rows.

Other set, having master list of unique products, calling it S2, has 2 columns (`ProductActualName, ProductCode, C3`) with 1000 Rows.

We want to join/map these two datasets over S1.ProductName and S2.ProductActualName , 
where these two columns never match by string matching. Because S1 is extracted from multiple different sources, names of products in S1.ProductName column can be differently worded, which contains enough information for a human to identify the correct product from the master and tag it uniquely to one of the names from the master list S2.

for example: 
`Audi R8 20mg` found in S2.ProductActualName can be worded as one of following in S1.ProductName

```
3221 R8 Audi 20
Audi R8 Audi 20mg
AUDI R 8 20 mg
AUDI R8 20
AUDIR8 20 
 and so on ...
```

basically possible human-readable combinations

**Current solution and problem in it**: We use string similarity libraries which work on distance based algorithms. With this, the results achieved are only 60-70% accurate, which is then checked manually to correct errors. The number of rows that are extracted are around a 500K and manually checking it is prone to error and becomes very tedious and time consuming. as this needs to be done every month.

**Example of some matched rows** :

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr7vC.png)

`The first column is the name extracted from different sources. Matched product name is after matching it with the master list. Sample data attached in email.`

here's the link to sample dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XxenDkLQYvWqus0wlEB5Uz1bs0r8iRuTGxw0S18lB38/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your 'Machine Learning Problem' is joining two dataframes in a string column that is not exactly the same.

To compute string similarity I will use something as [Levenshtein Distance](https://jellyfish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparison.html). In the jellyfish library you can find more string distance and select the more convenient for your problem.

Doing a bit more of NLP, my first idea will be to try [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation). This would require more engineering and I am not sure if it will give better results than simple Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: we tried the string similarity algorithms, on their own they produce approx 30% accurate results, they need manual correction to reach 80% accuracy. Hence it is not the best way as we conclude. Trying to find if any other domains have similar problems and solutions